# How to display stock_img() using Basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

According to Cartopy docs, `stock_img()` has only one (and default) option - a down sampled version of the Natural Earth shaded relief raster.

How do I display this image using Basemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

ax = plt.gca()

bmap = Basemap( projection='ortho', lat_0=45, lon_0=-100, resolution='l', ax=ax )
bmap.shadedrelief(scale=0.25)

plt.show()
```

[image: Output map]

Comment: Thanks very much! It works :) ps: I had to install  Python Imaging Library (PIL) to get it to work